# Integrate GWT Compile and selenium testing into a single maven goal

Tags: gwt, maven, selenium

I wanted to create a single gwt project which gets selenium tested just by typing 'mvn test'. That is, I need plugins to

1. compile,
2. bring up gwt server,
3. run selenium tests,
4. bring down gwt server.

I am not able to find something for steps 2 and 4. Does anyone have experience with this?

Thanks,
Aman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be straightforward if you use the `integration-test` phase instead:

1. `prepare-package` ⇒ `gwt:compile`
2. `pre-integration-test` ⇒ `jetty:start` (or `tomcat7:start`, or similar with another plugin)
3. `integration-test` ⇒ your selenium tests
4. `post-integration-test` ⇒ `jetty:stop` (or equivalent for another plugin)

If you'd like to run the selenium tests in DevMode, then I'm afraid there's no way to do it: there's no equivalent to `gwt:run` that would fork the process and allow its termination with another mojo (like `jetty:start`+`jetty:stop` vs. `jetty:run`)

Also, maybe you could use [Arquillian](http://arquillian.org) to start the server right from within your test, but that wouldn't solve the issue of either compiling the GWT module or launching DevMode (these can be launched from Java code, but it's discouraged)

Answer (score 0):

check the [gwt:test](http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/test-mojo.html) goal of [Maven GWT Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/)

In your pom:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <mode>selenium</mode>
                <selenium>localhost:4444/*firefox"</selenium>
```